# How does Gorouter handle 503 response

Tags: cloud-foundry

If there is HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable response from the server to the go-router will the go-router route the request to another node/instance ?. Is some configuration required at Go-router or will it handle automatically or does it not handle ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this is posed in below forum -

https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/list/cf-dev@lists.cloudfoundry.org/thread/XQYCMHILH3C47K436PSLZWIPBLFMYMDO/